# Outgoing connection with specific port are being blocked?

Tags: php, node.js, curl

I have bought a linux server from Godaddy . I tested to connect and get response from remote server , but it says CURL Failed . Also , it doesn't work on Node app too .

Here is the PHP Code :

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://dev.api/pay';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<xml>here</xml>" );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, '9085');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$output = curl_getinfo($ch);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($output);
echo "</pre>";

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

. Actually this code is working on localhost , but it doesn't work when accessed from the server.  If the outgoing connection is being blocked from the server's firewall i rented , how can i disable it or allow that port i intended to use only ?

Comment: You are trying to connect to it via port 8075, try using port 80.

Comment: No , you are not getting the point . The remote server is an API which is served on port 8075

Comment: i think you should ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com instead - but what do you get from `sudo iptables -S` ?  (btw iirc, unlike their web hosting serices, godaddy dedicated servers are overpriced, but that's none of my business )

Answer (score 0):

Do you have root access?
if so, use iptables to remove outgoing connection block.

If you do not have root acces, your host just does not allow outbound connections and there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Yeah , you are right . Since it is shared hosting , there is no way to do that since it requires root access . Thank You !